# How to calculate velocity and momentum of a rigid body

Tags: python, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a simple animation in which there are two planes and balls on the planes. There’s one ball on an inclined plane, and a couple of balls sitting on a horizontal plane below that ball. When the animation starts, the ball on the top rolls down the slope and collides with other balls. I need to calculate the velocity and momentum of the balls.

Here’s my code so far:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def distance_line(point1: Vector, point2: Vector) → float:
    return (point2 - point1).length

object = bpy.data.objects[“Sphere”]

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
prev_location = object.location.copy()

for frame in range(10, 151, 10):

    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    new_location = object.location

    distance = distance_line(new_location, prev_location)
    distance_vec = new_location - prev_location

    time = frame / 24
    velocity = distance_vec / time
    speed = distance / time
    print("frame", frame, "speed = ", speed, "velocity = ", velocity)
    prev_location = new_location.copy()
```

I have baked the animation otherwise the finding the location of the object in specific keyframes doesn’t work. So the problem with the above code is that if I let the for loop calculate the location for every key frame, it will show the exact same location value for consecutive frames. So, if you change the above for loop to:

```
for frame in range(2, 151, 1):
```

you will see that the speed output will be 0 or close to 0 in frames 2, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25, 28, 33, 35,...,
which doesn't make sense.

If I make the loop run for 10 steps I can see the change in location, but it’s still not a gradual change, so I can’t really calculate the exact velocity at a certain point in time. I even get inconsistent values for the velocity with this method. Is there any other way to do it in Blender?

[image]

Comment: i don't know how you "baked" your animation but in your blend file not every frame is keyframed!? If i bake your animation, every frame got a keyframe. So maybe you tell us how you did keyframe it?

Comment: I uploaded a baked version of the file. The result is still the same...